# jQuery - using the not() selector

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginning student learning jQuery, and the question says:

> Using the “not” built-in function, set the “text-decoration” CSS property to “underline” for all LI elements that do not contain a UL element.

I've tried a few different selectors, including:

```
$(li:not(li > ul)).css('text-decoration','underline');
$(li:not(li ul)).css('text-decoration','underline');
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the `:not` you're using is a selector, not a function.

Comment: Also, selectors still need to be strings.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using the `not()` function:

```
$('#myDemo > li').not(':has(ul)').css('text-decoration','underline');
```

Where `#myDemo` is the **ID** of the topmost `ul`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LKLz/6/)

Comment: This won't work. `$("li:not(li > ul)")` will always return all `li`s. i.e. `:not(li > ul)` will always be true for an `li`

Comment: Yes, this should work. Though it should be noted that `:has()` looks at descendants in all levels, not just immediate children.

Comment: The new version doesn't use `.not()`.

Comment: Ah, I see it has. (But it still uses a selector instead of the function.)

Comment: @PalashMondal - `$('li').not(':has(ul)').css(...);` should work and uses `.not()`

Comment: The above code does not work! [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/7LKLz/). It never can. Look at my answer

Comment: @OmShankar: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7LKLz/6/). Looking forward to your response...

Comment: @PalashMondal, you using a helper - the id `myDemo`, which makes things easier. That's exactly what I am doing, only class instead of id. Without having a reference to main parent, all efforts are useless and will match all the `<li>` in the DOM

Comment: Yes it is kind of. But lacks explanation why the use of `#myDemo`. And it was edited later than what I answered in the same approach :-)

Comment: As per SO practice, if one of your answer has gained recognition and upvotes, any edit made later to it due to comments should be notified in the answer, with an **UPDATE** or **EDIT**. It would make the comments meaningful and not make people like me look fools :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363602/1249219) given above will **NEVER** work. Look at the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/7LKLz/) to know why, and have your answer as well

---

**EXPLANATION**

This is a tricky stuff. The solution might seem simple but it may not work.
Any attempt made to return `<li>` by checking if it does not have a `<ul>` will be in vain.

This is because those `<li>` who have a `<ul>`, will (may) have `<li>`s inside that `<ul>`. So even if you have **unmatched** those `<li>`s, you have successfully matched their grand-childrens - the **innermost `<li>`s**.
At the end, therefore, **you have matched all the `<li>`** in the DOM

To understand it better, look at the following [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/7LKLz/), answer included

---

**ANSWER** - from the fiddle

I feel you will have to use an additional filter (suggestions welcome). IMO this can be done **only** by having the reference to the parent-most `<ul>`, by either class or id, and then filtering the results:

```
$('li').not(':has(ul)').css('text-decoration','underline');
// Matches all the LIs, and therefore not useful

$('li').filter(function() {
    return $('ul', this).length == 0;
}).css('color', 'blue');
// Nice try, but still Matches all the LIs


// This works, but need a reference to main parent, using a class, id etc.
$('li').not(':has(ul)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().hasClass('the-parent');
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with just a selector.

This should work:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    if($(this).children('ul').length == 0) {
        $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    }
});
```

Comment: This will probably work, but the question specifically asks to use the `.not()` function.

Comment: This won't work either, as the innermost `LI`s also match `$(this).children('ul').length == 0`. So finally you do `.css('text-decoration','underline')` to the `li`s specifically. All `li`s will have `underline`

Comment: @PalashMondal, Nice try, but you have missed few things: **1** - using the `not` built in function which is a must, required as per question, **2** - you are using the id `#myDemo`, this makes it a piece of cake. Thats exactly what I am doing in my answer, only class instead of id. **3** - using `each`, slower than `filter`